# Draw graphics at offset

Tags: c#, graphics

In my code, let's say I have the `PaintObject(Graphics g)`. In some other function, I want to call the `PaintObject` function to draw something at an offset, instead of drawing it at (0,0).

I know that in Java, I could use the `Graphics.create(x, y, width, height)` function to create a copy of my graphics object which I could use, which would draw within those bounds of the original graphics. Is there a way to do something similarly in C#?

Just to give you an example of what my code could look like:

```
class MyClass : UserControl {
  void PaintObject(Graphics g) {
    // Example: draw 10x10 rectangle
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Black), 0, 0, 10, 10);
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    // TODO: Paint object from PaintObject() at offset (50, 50)
  }
}
```

Comment: Use Graphics.TranslateTransform()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set a transformation on the `Graphics` object:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) 
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
    transformation.Translate(50, 50);

    g.Transform = transformation;
}
```

or

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) 
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.TranslateTransform(50, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `Graphics` method

```
public void TranslateTransform(float dx, float dy)
```

---

```
g.TranslateTransform(dx, dy);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Graphics.TranslateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4.aspx) method:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(50, 50);
    PaintObject(e.Graphics);
}
```